# Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Kali-Linux-2021.1-vbox-amd64. Callee RC: RPC_E_SERVERFAULT (0x80010105)

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, session

I have installed Kali Linux on VirtualBox but I had not been open for the last 1 month. Now I am trying to start Kali on VB but it gives me an error.

**Error:**

[image]

After closing this dialog box, it is opening another one to creating a process.

[image]
Any help is highly Apreciated.

Comment: Rebuild the host modules? Start the services?

Comment: How to do it? can you explain?

Comment: `vboxconfig`? `systemctl start vboxdrv.service`? Both as root.

Comment: @Bib please write a step or something like that so, I can understand I know systemctl but I am not able to enter kali... Is it any other way to execute it ??

Comment: Please post the full details of the error from virtualbox. This is clearly happening on a Windows host

Comment: If this is on a Windows host, then this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: I have edited my post.. and yes I am running virtual box on windows 8.

Comment: @Bib where should I ask then??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I got it working. 
I tried two things together, so I don't know which one solved my issue.

1. Open an administrator CMD and run

   ```
   bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
   ```

   You should get the response "The operation completed successfully." 
   Now restart your computer. 
   Source: [Solved: VirtualBox Failed to open session for Virtual Machine (Windows 10)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PN3E-E82q9U) (YouTube video).
2. I tried to reinstall vbox software without deleting the original files;
   so you download the installer from the Oracle webpage
   and just install it normally as if the application wasn't found on your PC. 
   After that, when opening the software
   you will get some notification to update guest editions,
   so go on and update it.